# Checking the values of cell contents in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to using VBA, and I wanted to know if something is possible. I have two workbooks in excel and they are quite large. What im trying to do is reference the values in a certain column, which are all phone numbers, in workbook one and find the matching value in workbook two. then when the matching value is found in workbook two copy the contents of a different cell in workbook one and paste them in a cell in workbook two. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  You could do something like the following:

```
Sub findAndPaste()
Dim row1 as Range, wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as workbook, sh1 as Worksheet, sh2 as Worksheet
Dim value1 as String, row2 as Range, value2 as String
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1Name")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2Name")
Set sh1 = wb1.sheets("SheetName")
Set sh2 = wb2.sheets("SheetName")
For each row1 in sh1.usedrange.rows
    value1 = row1.cells(1).value
    For each row2 in sh2.usedrange.rows
        value2 = row2.cells(1).value
        If value2 = value1 then
            row2.copy row1
            Exit For
        End if
        next 'row2
    next 'row1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "Is this possible", then the answer is yes. Also if that is the only question, this is not a programming question.